# Is there a way to post on Stack Exchange using non-graphical software?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

Computer enthusiasts often like to use non-graphical software for several reasons (saving CPU, efficiency, keyboard oriented, ...).

I would like to know if there are projects which aims to provide a non-graphical interface (ncurses for example) or terminal commands for the use of Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Have you tried lynx?

Comment: <del>I don’t think so, but there’s an API!</del> Actually, [see comment here](http://stackapps.com/questions/3220/anybody-up-for-terminal-frontends)

Comment: Stack Exchange has a write-access API deployed; it's only for their private use so far, but it seems likely that it will be released to the public in the future, and third-party tools for posting to the sites will follow.

Comment: @Rosinante Yes but a text-based browser is not intended for SE use. I'm looking a software like reportbug in Debian (for the asking question side).

Comment: There's [stackoverflow-cli, a *nix stackoverflow command line client](http://stackapps.com/q/2802/9), but it uses the API, so you're limited to the capability it provides. You won't currently be able to post questions and answers, just view them.

Comment: Well... remember that, depending on what stack you're on, some answers will eventually have pictures explaining the answer, and not just raw text. There is also the Mathematics stack...

Comment: Have you tried [NVDA](http://www.nvaccess.org/)?